# How to draw symmetrical parts of a circle

Tags: plotting, graphics

Let's consider the following simple case:

```
V = 1/2*(x^2 + y^2) + x^2*y - 1/3*y^3;
h = 0.3;
rad = 6*h;

S1 = ContourPlot[V, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> {h}, 
ContourShading -> False, ContourStyle -> {Darker[Green], Thick}, 
PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal :> "Speed", AspectRatio -> 1];
S2 = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> {rad},
ContourShading -> False, ContourStyle -> {Blue, Thick, Dashed}, 
PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal :> "Speed", AspectRatio -> 1];
P0 = Show[{S1, S2}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
PlotRange -> 1.5, ImageSize -> 550]
```

which gives

[image: chans]

We see, that the blue dashed circle intersects the green contour at the three openings (exits). I would like to draw the symmetrical parts of the circle inside these exits. By the term symmetrical, I mean with reverse curvature. I added by hand and with red color in the plot the symmetrical parts.

Any ideas how to obtain this?

**EDIT**

A copy of the above code (in version 9) can be found here:[code](http://www.mediafire.com/view/qagm2qdwanp7jaw/sample.nb).

Comment: @Anon See my edit where I provide a copy of the code in version 9.

Comment: You're aware that plotting the contour of $x^2+y^2$ at $\mathrm{rad}$ results in a circle of radius $\sqrt{\mathrm{rad}}$, I hope?

Comment: @Anon This file was created in version 9.0.0 and works fine in v 6.0.0, v 7.0.1 and v 8.0.0 and with some modifications (removing the PerformanceGoal option) also in v 5.2.0! So, it should work in v 9.0.1.

Comment: @RahulNarain Perfectly aware!

Comment: Sorry, I had to restart the kernel. I have already given the question a +1 because I thought it was well written btw.

Comment: @All All the suggested answers are more or less equally good. So, I upvoted all of them but I don't know which one to accept. Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 13):

First we need to find the intersection points. It's more convenient to find them as angles around the circle, rather than $(x,y)$ coordinates, otherwise we might not be sure what order they're in.

```
r = Sqrt[rad];
angles = θ /. Solve[{(V /. {x -> r Cos[θ], y -> r Sin[θ]}) == h, 0 <= θ < 2 π}, θ]
```

> `{1.32755, 1.81404, 3.42195, 3.90843, 5.51634, 6.00283}`

By inspection we see that the arcs we want are from the first to the second, then the third to the fourth, and the fifth to the sixth point. With a little geometry, we can define a function to draw the reflected arc between any two points on a circle.

```
reflectedArc[{x_, y_}, r_, {θ1_, θ2_}] :=
 Circle[{x, y} + r {Cos[θ1] + Cos[θ2], Sin[θ1] + Sin[θ2]}, r, {π + θ1, π + θ2}]
```

We apply this onto our pairs of points and produce the final figure.

```
arcs = Graphics[{Red, reflectedArc[{0, 0}, r, #] & /@ Partition[angles, 2]}];
Show[{S1, S2, arcs}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 PlotRange -> 1.5, ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image]

(By the way, I must point out that you could have defined `S2` much more easily as `Graphics[{Blue, Thick, Dashed, Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[rad]]}]`.)

Answer (score 11):

This solution is different from the other solutions in that it does not use the fact that the blue curve is a circle. Instead, we search the interior of the blue curve for points which will lie on the boundary when reflected.

I recast your problem statement as

```
f1[x_, y_] := 1/2*(x^2 + y^2) + x^2*y - 1/3*y^3;
f2[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
h = 0.3; rad = 6*h;

S1 = ContourPlot[f1 @@ {x, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   Contours -> {h}, ContourShading -> False, 
   ContourStyle -> {Darker[Green], Thick}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   PerformanceGoal :> "Speed", AspectRatio -> 1];
S2 = ContourPlot[f2 @@ {x, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   Contours -> {rad}, ContourShading -> False, 
   ContourStyle -> {Blue, Thick, Dashed}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   PerformanceGoal :> "Speed", AspectRatio -> 1];
```

Then I found the points of intersection, and lines to be reflected across. This is a weak point in the solution, as it depends on manually identifying the lines to reflect across.

```
pts = {x, y} /. Solve[{f2[x, y] == rad, f1[x, y] == h}, {x, y}, Reals]; // Quiet
lines = Partition[pts, 2];
```

Define reflections geometrically (`Projection` is built-in, that was new to me)

```
Rejection[u_, v_] := u - Projection[u, v];
Reflection[{a_, b_}, c_] := a + Projection[c - a, b - a] - Rejection[c - a, b - a]
```

Then use my `Reflection` and the `RegionFunction` option

```
S3 = ContourPlot[f2 @@ Reflection[#, {x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, f2[x, y] < rad], 
   Contours -> {rad}, ContourShading -> False, 
   ContourStyle -> {Red, Thick, Dashed}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   PerformanceGoal :> "Speed", AspectRatio -> 1] & /@ lines;
```

And finally combine plots

```
P0 = Show[{S1, S2, S3}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  RotateLabel -> False, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
  PlotRange -> 1.5, ImageSize -> 550]
```

Here is a picture with your function, as well as one with `f2[x_,y_]:=x^4+y^6`
[image: Reflected Contours]

Comment: Neat approach.  FYI, [`ReflectionTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReflectionTransform.html) and [`ReflectionMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReflectionMatrix.html) are built in, too.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2, I haven't played with those enough to be comfortable with them. What I don't like is that they use the normals to the lines/surfaces which often means some more effort on my part to find the normals before I can use them.

Comment: Conveniently `Cross[{a, b}]` makes a vector normal to the 2D vector `{a, b}`.

Comment: Very nice! Computing `S3` is a little slow, but you can make it faster by `// Evaluate`ing the `f2 @@ Reflection[#, {x, y}]`.

Comment: If `f1[x_, y_] := 1/2*(x^2 + y^2) - x*y^2;` the method does not work and the reflected arcs are wrong! any suggestions?

Comment: It looks good to me, but maybe you would prefer `lines = FindClusters[pts, 2];` in this case. Like I said, automatically finding the lines to reflect across is a weak point in the solution and may need to be done by hand.

Comment: More explicitly, `lines` is a list of pairs of points like the following `lines = {{pts[[1]], pts[[3]]}, {pts[[2]], pts[[4]]}};`

Answer (score 11):

Let me join this party.

I propose a purely graphical approach (it looks like quite compact):

```
f1[x_, y_] := 1/2*(x^2 + y^2) + x^2*y - 1/3*y^3;
f2[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
h = 0.3; rad = 6 h;

Show[Normal@ContourPlot[f2[x, y] == rad, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
    ContourStyle -> {Red,Thick}, RegionFunction -> (f1[#1, #2] < h &), MaxRecursion -> 4] /.
     Line[{p1_, pp___, p2_}] :> GeometricTransformation[Line[{p1, pp, p2}], 
       ReflectionTransform[Cross[p2 - p1], p2]], 
 ContourPlot[f1[x, y] == h, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Darker[Green], Thick}]]
```

Here `Normal` converts `GraphicsComplex` to `Line`s. Then I reflect this lines around ending points.

[image]

Comment: Rats!  Beat me!. :) +1.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for tip with `Cross`! Now it looks  a bit better.

Comment: I guess this is the only approach that both (i) works for things other than circles, and (ii) doesn't require manual inspection that the intersection points are in the right order. Nice!

Comment: Probably the most general solution..+1

Comment: @ybeltukov very instructive, compact. Learned a lot.

Answer (score 4):

We can try as the following.

```
V = 1/2*(x^2 + y^2) + x^2*y - 1/3*y^3;
h = 0.3; rad = 6*h; center = {0, 0};
pts = {x, y} /.NSolve[{x^2 + y^2 == 6*h, V == h}, {x, y},Reals];(*find intersections*)
midpts = (Mean /@ Partition[pts, 2]);(*Find mid points the black ones*)
dist =Norm /@ midpts;(*Distance from center*)
Off[Divide::infy];(*equations of straight line joining center and mid points*)
eqs = (y - #[[2]] == (x - #[[1]]) First@Ratios@(center - #) & /@ midpts) /. 
   a_ == ComplexInfinity -> (x == 0) /.ComplexInfinity == b_ -> (y == 0);
(*pattern check for straight lines x=0 and y=0*)
Off[NSolve::ratnz];(*Find equation of the reverse circles*)res = 
 MapThread[Total[({x, y}-First@(Select[{x, y} /.Chop@NSolve[{#1, Norm[#2 - {x, y}] == #3},
   {x, y},Reals], # != center &]))^2] == rad &, {eqs, midpts,dist}];
```

We find collinear point on the line joining the center and the mid point (in black) lying at the same distance from the mid points as the distance from the midpoint to the center. In `res` we have the equations of the reverse circles centered at those points. You can `ContourPlot` these circle equations now on a right x-domain to get the right segment. Red and black points are drawn on you last `Show` command using `Epilog`.

```
reverse = 
  MapThread[
   ContourPlot[#1, Evaluate@Flatten@{x, #2[[1]]}, {y, -2, 2}, 
     Contours -> {rad}, ContourShading -> False, 
     ContourStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
     PerformanceGoal :> "Speed", AspectRatio -> 1] &, {res,Transpose /@ Partition[pts, 2]}];
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not particularly clever but works:

```
V = 1/2*(x^2 + y^2) + x^2*y - 1/3*y^3;
cp = ContourPlot[{V == 0.3, x^2 + y^2 == 1.8}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
sol = NSolve[{V == 0.3, x^2 + y^2 == 1.8}, {x, y}];
roots = {x, y} /. sol
rem[u_] := Module[{f}, f[x_] := (f[Reverse@x] = Sequence[]; x); f /@ u];
ans = rem[Nearest[roots, #, 2] & /@ roots];
cent[{{p_, q_}, {r_, s_}}] := 
 First@Cases[{x, y} /. 
    Chop[NSolve[{(x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 == 
        1.8, (x - r)^2 + (y - s)^2 == 1.8}, {x, y}]], Except[{0, 0}]];
vec = {#, cent[#]} & /@ ans;

arcs = {#[[2]], 
    Arg[Complex @@@ (Map[Function[x, x - #[[2]]], #[[1]]])]} & /@ vec;
Show[cp, Graphics[Circle[#[[1]], Sqrt[1.8], #[[2]]] & /@ arcs]]
```

Essentially, just find the intersections, second circle centre and arcs then compose. Styling could be altered.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is like Rahul's solution only imagine that we didn't realize that we could use trigonometry to find the origin of the reflected arc analytically, and we also didn't realize polar coordinates were more suited for the task hehe.

```
(* Find the points of intersection. *)
sol = Solve[{
    V == h,
    x^2 + y^2 == rad
    }, {x, y}, Reals];

(* Find three sets with two points in each. Group by how close they \
are to each other. *)
pts = FindClusters[{x, y} /. sol, 3];

(* Find the origin of the other circle that intersects each set of \
coordinates *)
origos = {x, y} /. First@FindInstance[{
                Norm[{x, y} - #[[1]]] == Norm[{x, y} - #[[2]]],
                Norm[{x, y} - #[[1]]] == Sqrt[rad],
                Norm[{x, y}] > Sqrt[rad]
                }, {x, y}, Reals] & /@ pts;

(* Create data list: {origin,intersection 1,intersection 2} *)

data = MapThread[{#, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]} &, {origos, pts}];

(* Generate the circle segments *)
circles = Circle[
          #[[1]], Norm[#[[1]] - #[[2]]], {
       ArcTan @@ (#[[2]] - #[[1]]),
       ArcTan @@ (#[[3]] - #[[1]])
      }
          ] & /@ data;

(* Draw. *)
Show[P0, Graphics[{Red, circles}] ]
```

[image: plot]