# Problem with ContourPlot [Not smooth curve]

Tags: plotting, graphics

Here is my code

```
V[x_, y_] := ω^2/2*(x^2 + y^2) - \[Epsilon]*(-(x^6/6) + 5/2*x^4*y^2 - 5/2*x^2*y^4 + y^6/6);
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;

ω = 1; \[Epsilon] = 1;
h = 1.1;
rad = 1.8*h;
xmin = 2;

P00 = Show[{{Normal@
  ContourPlot[f[x, y] == rad, {x, -xmin, xmin}, {y, -xmin, xmin}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Red, Dashed, Thick}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
   PerformanceGoal :> "Quality", 
   RegionFunction -> (V[#1, #2] < h &), MaxRecursion -> 4] /. 
 Line[{p1_, pp___, p2_}] :> 
  GeometricTransformation[Line[{p1, pp, p2}], 
   ReflectionTransform[Cross[p2 - p1], p2]], 
 ContourPlot[V[x, y] == h, {x, -xmin, xmin}, {y, -xmin, xmin}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.007]}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 PerformanceGoal :> "Quality"]}}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 RotateLabel -> False, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None, ImageSize -> 550]
```

and this is the corresponding output

[image]

As you can see, there is an unwanted angle in the red dashed line. It should be smooth as the rest five since the function is symmetrical. I tried to increase the `PlotPoints` and the `MaxRecursion` but the problem remains.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is because of the post-processing you are applying to the contour lines. The lowermost "line" is actually two `Line` primitives which are individually being reflected.

Comment: @Rahul So, how can this be fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe one of the other solutions in [your previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36724/484) doesn't have this problem?

Comment: it would seem easy enough to just draw those arcs, or construct a function that contours properly without the  reflection

Comment: @Rahul This solution is the only one that can cope with complicated V functions. Why the angle appears in the last red line and not to the other five? Since the function is symmetrical can we move this abnormality to another line?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is deals with a problem caused by specific post-processing by the OP and is very localized.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem occurs because

```
z = Normal@ContourPlot[f[x, y] == rad, {x, -xmin, xmin}, {y, -xmin, xmin}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Red, Dashed, Thick}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
   PerformanceGoal :> "Quality", RegionFunction -> (V[#1, #2] < h &), MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

contains seven `Line`s, not six (because the `Line` representing the original dashed circle has a beginning and an end). This can be seen from

```
Position[z, Line[y__], Infinity]
{* {{1, 1, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 1, 4}, {1, 1, 3, 1, 
  5}, {1, 1, 3, 1, 6}, {1, 1, 3, 1, 7}, {1, 1, 3, 1, 8}} *}
```

From

```
Table[Length[z[[1, 1, 3, 1, i, 1]]], {i, 2, 8}]
{* {248, 743, 769, 687, 738, 722, 448} *}
```

it is evident that the first and last of the `Line`s must be merged, and the last `Line` then deleted

```
z[[1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1]] = Join[z[[1, 1, 3, 1, 8, 1]], z[[1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1]]]; 
z = Delete[z, {1, 1, 3, 1, 8}]
```

With `z` thus modified,

```
Show[{{z /. Line[{p1_, pp___, p2_}] :> GeometricTransformation[Line[{p1, pp, p2}], 
   ReflectionTransform[Cross[p2 - p1], p2]], 
   ContourPlot[V[x, y] == h, {x, -xmin, xmin}, {y, -xmin, xmin}, 
    ContourStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.007]}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
    PerformanceGoal :> "Quality"]}}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using `ContourPlot` for such a simple thing as a *circle* is like, well, inviting [the guys from CSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSI:_Miami) to find out who has eaten your apple. A circle has a very simple parametric form and you should rather use [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) for this:

```
pm = Normal[
   ParametricPlot[rad {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed, Thick}, 
    RegionFunction -> (V[#1, #2] < h &)]] /. 
  Line[{p1_, pp___, p2_}] :> 
   GeometricTransformation[Line[{p1, pp, p2}], 
    ReflectionTransform[Cross[p2 - p1], p2]]
```

It is by magnitudes faster and it really only draws the lines required. Therefore, your `Line` replacement will instantly work.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach, contour just one of the segments, reflect it then make 6 rotated copies of the arc..

```
 P00 = Show[{{Normal@
     ContourPlot[f[x, y] == rad, {x, -xmin, xmin}, {y, -xmin, xmin}, 
     ContourStyle -> {Red, Dashed, Thick}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
     PerformanceGoal :> "Quality", 
     RegionFunction -> (V[#1, #2] < h && 
                        Abs[ArcTan[#2, #1] ] < Pi/6 &),
           MaxRecursion -> 4] /. 
     Line[{p1_, pp___, p2_}] :> 
       GeometricTransformation[Line[{p1, pp, p2}], 
        Table[ Composition[RotationTransform[i Pi/3], 
                           ReflectionTransform[Cross[p2 - p1], p2]], {i, 0, 5}]] , 
     ContourPlot[V[x, y] == h, {x, -xmin, xmin}, {y, -xmin, xmin}, 
       ContourStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.007]}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
       PerformanceGoal :> "Quality"]}}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
       RotateLabel -> False, 
       FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
       PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None, ImageSize -> 550]
```

this of course relies on a bit of luck that the segment we picked is a smooth one..'

Answer (score 1):

Approach from my comment, getting rid of the reflection and directly contour plotting the outer circles.  This is actually slower, but somehow a more satisfying approach..

```
V[x_, y_] := ω^2/2*(x^2 + y^2) - \[Epsilon]*(-(x^6/6) + 5/2*x^4*y^2 - 5/2*x^2*y^4 + y^6/6);
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;

ω = 1; \[Epsilon] = 1;
h = 1.1;
rad = 1.8*h;
xmin = 2;

pint = {x, y} /. NSolve[ V[x, y] == h && f[x, y] == rad , {x, y}];
pp = First@SortBy[pint, Abs[#[[1]]] &];
z = y /. NSolve[ pp[[1]]^2 + (y + pp[[2]])^2 == rad && y^2 > rad] // First;
cp  = -z Table[  {Sin[n Pi/3], Cos[n Pi/3]} , {n, 1, 6}];
P00 = Show[{{Normal@
    ContourPlot[
       Evaluate[((x - #[[1]])^2 + (y - #[[2]])^2 == rad) & /@ cp],
         {x, -xmin, xmin}, {y, -xmin, xmin}, 
       ContourStyle -> {{Red, Dashed, Thick}}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
       PerformanceGoal :> "Quality", 
       RegionFunction -> (V[#1, #2] < h &), MaxRecursion -> 4], 
    ContourPlot[V[x, y] == h, {x, -xmin, xmin}, {y, -xmin, xmin}, 
      ContourStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.007]}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
      PerformanceGoal :> "Quality"]}}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
      RotateLabel -> False, 
      FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
      PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None, ImageSize -> 550]
```

(the result is identical to @bbgodfry's result so I wont bother posting the graphic.)